# VB: Referencing a variable by name in a conditional

Tags: vb.net

I am an amateur programmer and in working with a friend and cannot find a solution to our coding dilemma.

We need to be able to compare if a Variable matches data found in second variable, but the first Variable to be searched is to be dependent on the contents of a third variable. (The third variable would name the first variable to be searched)

```
Var1, Var2, Var3 ... Var100 'Each with their own values and datatypes;
Var45 = 25
Vartocheck1 = "Var45"
Vattocheck2 = 25
If Vartocheck1 = Vartocheck2 Then
(Stuff)
End If
```

Essentially, I was wondering if there was a good way to compare two variables, most likely in an If-then statement, where one of the two variables is decided by a third variable's contents.

The idea is Vartocheck1 would be a string, containing the NAME of the variable whose value I want to check against Vartocheck2. The issue is that the variables in the code (in my example: Var1, Var2, Var3 ... Var100) are defined as the process runs, but an external excel chart, when referenced, can change certain variables during the program's execution. I could accomplish what I need with about a million nested if-then statements, but that is slow and messy, and I am hoping there is another way.

I have looked into arrays, but implementing the massive number and size of the arrays would be daunting and require an entire project rewrite.

Is there any good method for comparing a variable like this?

Comment: `If Var45 = 25 Then...` or `Var187 = 25 : If Var45 = Var187 Then...`  you dont need to assign the target value to a variable to use it in a statement. and you *cant* assign a variable name to a string and do anything meaningful with it.  They are already *variables*.

Comment: @BadProgrammer If two separate applications need access to the same data then there is one very obvious and natural solution - use a database. Trying to let Excel reach into your application and manipulate variables by name is bordering on insanity. Don't do that.  Alternatively, you may want to allow your process to operate as an out-of-process ActiveX server where you could expose public methods to clients (like Excel) which could perform the required functions.  To suggest anything more specific would need more detail about what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a concept called reflection. This SO question explains it:

[How to get the variable names types, and values in the current class or Method in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859780/how-to-get-the-variable-names-types-and-values-in-the-current-class-or-method-i)

Based on that I have quickly created the following class:

```
Public Class Class1


Public This As String
Public That As Boolean

Public Function ListVar() As Boolean


    Dim fields As System.Reflection.FieldInfo() = Me.GetType().GetFields()

    For Each fld As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In fields
        Dim name As String = fld.Name
        Dim value = fld.GetValue(Me)
        Dim typ As Type = fld.FieldType
        Debug.Print(name)
    Next
    Return True
End Function
End Class
```

You can call the ListVar function from anywhere by doing this:

```
Dim c As New Class1
c.ListVar()
```

Obviously this is not production ready, but should give you a start.

Comment: This does answer OP's question, but I really think it is not the correct solution to the problem.  OP has asked a pretty strong [XY question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) and this is just going to let them make things worse.

Comment: I disagree. If you read closely the problem the OP is trying to solve is that of having to compare variables but not knowing the names of these variables beforehand. Reflection is pretty much the only trick in the book to get back at these unknown names. XY Problem or not, my proposed solution offers a learning moment (an important design principle such as reflection) without having to guess as to the real reason for this less than stellar design (saves me time) and solves the problem. Win-Win-Win ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While I still think this is an XY problem, one convenient container in .net is [a dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).  This allows you to store key-value pairs which can be of any type.  This gives you some of the tools you would get with a database (which may be a better solution in this case).  For example :

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic    
Module Module1
    Dim ValueDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)    
    Sub Main()
        Dim r As New Random
        'Fill the dictionary with keys "Var1" -> "Var100"
        'Fill the values with random integers
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            ValueDict.Add("Var" & i.ToString, r.Next)
        Next

        'Extract a variable by name
        Dim extractedVar As Integer
        If ValueDict.TryGetValue("Var23", extractedVar) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Var23 has value :" & extractedVar.ToString())
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Var23 does not exist in the dictionary")
        End If

        'enumerate all values
        For Each valuePair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In ValueDict
            Console.WriteLine("Variable " & valuePair.Key & _
                              " = " & valuePair.Value.ToString())
        Next

        'Get a variable by number
        Dim varNumber As Integer = 72
        If ValueDict.TryGetValue("Var" & varNumber.ToString(), extractedVar) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Var" & varNumber.ToString() & _
                              " has value :" & extractedVar.ToString())
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Var" & varNumber.ToString() & _
                              " does not exist in the dictionary")
        End If    
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub    
End Module
```

Other types of operations :

```
        'Check if value exists, Assign a new value or update an existing value
        Dim newVal As Integer = 12345
        Dim varName As String = "Var147"
        If Not ValueDict.ContainsKey(varName) Then
            Console.WriteLine(varName & " does not currently exist")
        End If
        ValueDict.Item(varName) = newVal
        Console.WriteLine(varName & " now has value :" & ValueDict.Item(varName).ToString())

        'Delete a value
        ValueDict.Remove(varName)
        If Not ValueDict.ContainsKey(varName) Then
            Console.WriteLine(varName & " does not currently exist")
        End If
```