# Hierarchy in a structure

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a datatable which reads all the contents of a csv file(all working fine here). This datatable is then sorted into a "Structure" with the required columns. Within this structure is a set of elements like
`Dim FUND_TYPE As String
 Dim FUND_SITE As String
 Dim FUND_DIR As String
 Dim FUND_DEPT As String
 Dim FUND_MNGR_1 As String
 Dim FUND_MNGR_2 As String
 Dim FUND_MNGR_3 As String`
What I am trying to do is get a manager(FUND_MNGR_1) from the structure and pass it to a subroutine. Then go to the next manager(FUND_MNGR_2) and pass it to the same subroutine. There are other elements in the structure which need to be action-ed separately.

There arises the question of whether we can loop through all the elements in a structure? Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried array or list?

Comment: @the_lotus nope, but thank you for the advise. I wanted a way to make use of a structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449945/1383168